# IIS 10/Powershell - How to "browse" the PSPath?

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to create a script for our AAR-server that should create webfarms and the corresponding url rewrite rules. The script will try to delete the rule before creating it and in my case the rule does exist, but it won't find it:

```
WARNING: Target configuration object 'system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules/ARR_dst.test.refusjon- 
8083_lb is not found at path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'.
```

Is there any way to "browser" the path in IIS in order to verify if it does really exisit in path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'. I assume so based on all the examples I have found on, but still - not sure on my installation.

So how to find the path to all rules?

```
Clear-WebConfiguration -pspath $psPath  -filter $filterRoot
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath $psPath -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules" -name "." -value @{name=$ruleName;patternSyntax='Regular Expressions';stopProcessing='False'}
```

Comment: Might be the answer to my question, but still a bit cumbersome https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/using-configuration-editor-generate-scripts

Comment: This did actually delete the rule 

2019-11-08 15:50:25,740 [Pipeline Execution Thread] DEBUG root [(null)] - Delete rewriterule=system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules/rule[@name='ARR_dst.test.foventetinntekt-9010_lb'] with pspath=MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST

Comment: As you are targeting IIS 10, use IISAdministration cmdlets please https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/iisadministration-powershell-cmdlets

Comment: Problem is @LexLi that being all new to IIS and dependent on the "Generate script" in the Configuration Editor - that one creates the script as above, and apparantly not using the IISAdministration cmdlets. :-(

Comment: IIS Manager might even generate broken scripts, so I don't really recommend that. Scripts based on IISAdministration should look quite similar to the C# sample code on each IIS configuration reference page, where in general everything maps to the XML config file easily. The legacy cmdlets were designed in such a bad syntax.

Comment: Could you share your PowerShell script?`ForEach($farm in $farms)
{   
    # Create the farm
    .\appcmd.exe set config  -section:webFarms /+"[name='$($farm.name)']" /commit:apphost

    ForEach($server in $farm.Servers)
    {
        # Add server to farm
        .\appcmd.exe set config  -section:webFarms /+"[name='$($farm.name)'].[address='$($server.address)']" /commit:apphost
    } # URL Rewrite
 .\appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules /+"[name='ARR_$($farm.name)_lb', patternSyntax='Wildcard',stopProcessing='True']" /commit:apphost`

Comment: `.\appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules /"[name='ARR_$($farm.name)_lb',patternSyntax='Wildcard',stopProcessing='True']".match.url:"*"  /commit:apphost
 .\appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules /"[name='ARR_$($farm.name)_lb',patternSyntax='Wildcard',stopProcessing='True']".action.type:"Rewrite"  /"[name='ARR_$($farm.name)_lb',patternSyntax='Wildcard',stopProcessing='True']".action.url:"http://$($farm.name)/{R:0}"  /commit:apphost
}`

Comment: @JalpaPanchal - it is quite a lot of text, but an example 

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath $psPath  -filter $filterConditions -name "." -value @{input='{HTTP_HOST}';pattern=$urlHttpHost;matchType='0';ignoreCase='True';negate='False'}
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath $psPath  -filter $filterConditions -name "." -value @{input='{QUERY_STRING}';pattern=$urlPattern;matchType='0';ignoreCase='True';negate='False'}
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath $psPath  -filter $filterRoot  -name "stopProcessing" -value "True"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best, or, only thing I've found so far is to use the configuration editor and "Generate scripts"

[Using Configuration Editor: Generate Scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/using-configuration-editor-generate-scripts)